# Mapping bunch of integers to some strings with less repetition

Tags: c#, strings, integer

I have this switch case statement which maps an integer to a string. There can be multiple integers that maps to same string. objective here is to not to duplicate the string value and retrive the string value by passing the id.

```
    public const int Product1 = 111;
    public const int Product2 = 112;
    public const int Product3 = 113;
    public const int Product4 = 114;
    public const int Product5 = 115;

    public const int Product11 = 133;
    public const int Product12 = 134;
    public const int Product13 = 135;
    public const int Product14 = 136;
    public const int Product15 = 137;


    public static string GetName(int productId)
    {
        switch (productId)
        {
            case Product1:
            case Product11:
                return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
            case Product2:
            case Product12:
                return "Consectetur adipiscing elit";
            case Product3:
            case Product13:
                return "Ut eu dui ut lorem scelerisque tempo";
            case Product4:
            case Product14:
                return "Sed feugiat magna sed vestibulum euismod";
            case Product5:
            case Product15:
                return "Duis ornare libero sed massa dictum";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Is there any other ways I can accomplish this task with zero repetition with a nice and tidy code?

Comment: How about having a simple `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: then I have to duplicate the name for each key that maps to same name values which is not ideal in case if I want to edit the name in future eg: d.add(1,"abc); d.add(2,"abc");

Comment: no that's not true. Let me put together an example to show you how

Comment: BTW this code does not seem to be a real code which is against the [CodeReview's question standards](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652). Also the question's title should say what does your code do rather than what review are you seeking for.

Comment: updated the question title, I cannot use actual product names as they are copyrighted. so I used some dummy texts to replace em. method and the properties are pretty much real.

Comment: Honestly, there's so much wrong here I wouldn't even know where to begin a review. Why would you even have a method to retrieve the name of a product? Why would product IDs and names be hardcoded in code? What are you going to do with other properties of a product?

Comment: @BCdotWEB its a legacy code/db, and they really don't want me to add another column to the product table so this is what I have to work with. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Constants

- Move your name constants into dedicated const fields

```
private const string Name1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
private const string Name2 = "Consectetur adipiscing elit";
private const string Name3 = "Ut eu dui ut lorem scelerisque tempo";
private const string Name4 = "Sed feugiat magna sed vestibulum euismod";
private const string Name5 = "Duis ornare libero sed massa dictum";
```

Or simply just

```
private const string Name1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                     Name2 = "Consectetur adipiscing elit",
                     Name3 = "Ut eu dui ut lorem scelerisque tempo",
                     Name4 = "Sed feugiat magna sed vestibulum euismod",
                     Name5 = "Duis ornare libero sed massa dictum";
```

#### Define mappings between ProductIds and Names

```
private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, string> ProductNameMappings = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { Product1, Name1 },
    { Product11, Name1 },
    { Product2, Name2 },
    { Product12, Name2 },
    { Product3, Name3 },
    { Product13, Name3 },
    { Product4, Name4 },
    { Product14, Name4 },
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

- I've defined it as a static, readonly immutable collection to prevent any unintentional change in these steady, changeless mappings

#### Use the mappings to perform a simple lookup

```
public static string GetName(int productId)
    =>  ProductNameMappings.TryGetValue(productId, out var name) ? name : string.Empty;
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> lets say we have 20 products and 10 of them have the same name. but it takes 20 lines to add them to this dictionary.

As it said by QuasiStellar there is no such rule which prevents you to define more than 1 dictionary entry in a single line, like

```
private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, string> ProductNameMappings = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { Product1, Name1 }, { Product2, Name2 }, { Product3, Name3 }, { Product4, Name4 },
    { Product11, Name1 }, { Product12, Name2 }, { Product13, Name3 },{ Product14, Name4 },
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Or if you have a handful of products which should be mapped to the same name then you can do something like this as well

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Name1Mappings = new[] { Product1, Product12 , ... }.ToDictionary(p => p, _ => Name1); 

private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, string> ProductNameMappings = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { Product2, Name2 },
    { Product12, Name2 },
    ...,
}
.Union(Name1Mappings)
.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Comment: I like it, I am spitballing here, is there way of me to reduce the number of lines....lets say we have 20 products and 10 of em has the same name. but it takes 20 lines to add them to this dictionary.

Comment: @Pahan you can do it all in one line. Just don't use linebreaks. Clarity of code is not always about how short it is.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that you're going to have a bad time if you hard code products. Your complaint seems to be about how repetitive it is (which is true) and how many lines it takes up (also true), but also if you make any changes to your inventory you have to go touch the code and recompile.

I honestly think you'd be better off moving the inventory/name mapping to a file (CSV, JSON, etc.) and just read the file into your dictionary.

Comment: its a legacy code/db, and they really don't want me to add another column to the product table so this is what I have to work with. :( plus this is for only set of product ids, not all of em. I like the idea of adding json file, but when comes to performance is it same as dictionary/switch case?

Comment: @Pahan - you can load the JSON file when the application starts, or you can lazy-load it only when you're trying to access the information. Once you load it, though, you load it into a dictionary and you cache/keep it, so there's no performance difference at all beyond the initial loading. If there are only a few entries then I wouldn't expect a noticeable hit to performance, and if there are a lot of entries then I would expect you really don't want to hard-code it!